# MVC AJAX no response from controler

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm having issues regarding AJAX request which POST-s form to controler but no response back. No success nor Error. I tried all sorts of combinations, even left some of code commented which also didn't work, in some cases it gives response but error, such as if i put timeout on ajax (which is expected). i even tried simple requests with no form submit but rather couple of varibles but sucess response never came. 
Any suggestions?

My Jquery:

function SubmitForm() {

```
var dataString;
if ($("#UpitId").attr("enctype") == "multipart/form-data") {
    //this only works in some browsers.
    //purpose? to submit files over ajax. because screw iframes.
    //also, we need to call .get(0) on the jQuery element to turn it into a regular DOM element so that FormData can use it.
    dataString = new FormData($("#UpitId").get(0));
    contentType = false;
    processData = false;
}

$.ajax({
    url: "/Upit/Uspjeh/",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    //dataType: "html",
    traditional: true,
    data: dataString,
    //data: { Sadrzaj:"Test Sadržaj",Eposta:"marko@gmail.com"},
    contentType: contentType,
    processData: processData,
    //timeout:1,
    sucess: function (data) {
        alert("Sucess");          
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

}

Controller:

[HttpPost]

```
    public ActionResult Uspjeh(FormaZaUnos model, string Send, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                    string fileName = "";
                    byte[] fileText = null;
                    int numFiles = 0;

                    string IncidentId = _repository.CreateCrmRecord(model, fileName, fileText, numFiles);

                    if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
                    {

                        numFiles = Request.Files.Count;
                        for (int i = 0; i < numFiles; i++)
                        {

                            var upFile = Request.Files[i];
                            //var file = Request.Files[0];
                            if (upFile != null && upFile.ContentLength > 0)
                            {

                                var allowedExtensions = new[] { ".doc", ".xlsx", ".txt", ".jpeg", ".docx", ".xls" };


                                if (allowedExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(upFile.FileName)))
                                {
                                    _repository.CreateNotesWithAttachment(Request.Files[i], IncidentId);

                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }


                    //return Json("chamara", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

                    return Json(new { sucess=true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

                    //var storiesObj = new { success = true, stories = "Test" };
                    //return storiesObj;
                    //return Json("'Success':'true'");
                    //return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "Your message successfuly sent!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    //return Content("uspjeh");
                }
            }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: any chance that your `string IncidentId = _repository.CreateCrmRecord(model, fileName, fileText, numFiles);` is timing out?? since you are dealing with database here..

Comment: the record is created normally, every time.

Comment: ok so you say if you debug that line there is not hold or wait time for that part of execution?

Comment: 1,536 ms in debug mode. is that too much?

Comment: no that's not a problem then... how about this one `_repository.CreateNotesWithAttachment` ... no problem here too?

Comment: i commented theese lines and debbuged but still no response

Comment: I am not sure if this was a copy & paste issue while you posted the question but. There is  a mismatch in the code block.. `{` and `}` so with current code the `return null;` is technically outside the Actionresult..

Comment: it's copy paste issue :)

Comment: this is getting tough... ok.. do you see any console errors? also remove all the code in the controller except the return statement and check.. I am sorry I really cant see any other possible issue